# JavaHelp Swing wrong rendering of HTML vertical-align

Tags: java, html, css, swing, javahelp

I know that the JavaHelp HTML rendering is known to be poor/outdated but I would like to know if there is a workaround exists to fix the following problem. The following HTML fragment

```html
<html>
    <head>
        <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8">
  </head>
  <body>
      <div>
          <span>This is a </span>
          <img style="vertical-align:middle" src='./_LaTeX_cvode_solve.xml_1.png' /> 
          <span>formula</span>
      </div>
  </body>
</html>
```

is wrongly rendered in JavaHelp by javax.help.SwingHelpUtilities:

[image]

the (correct) rendering in Firefox is the following

[image]

What are other ways (that could be supported by JavaHelp) to verticaly align an inline image w.r.t. text ? I have tested many popular ways but none worked so far. So if someone who has already struggled with JavaHelp may give some hints I would be very grateful.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Java Swing's support for [CSS](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/16/docs/api/java.desktop/javax/swing/text/html/CSS.html) is very hit and miss. Here is the list of attributes supported (with notes):

> The following describes the CSS properties that are supported by the rendering engine:
>
> - font-family
> - ..
> - text-decoration (with the exception of blink and overline)
> - **vertical-align (*only sup and super*)**
> - text-align (justify is treated as center)
> - ..
> - list-style-position

So your best shot might be to use the actual HTML for the formula, with super and sub-script.

**Note:** Java-FX offers the [`WebView`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/api/javafx/scene/web/WebView.html) which (AFAIU) embeds an actual browser.

Comment: OK so bad news. Maybe using Cobra/LoboBrowser could be another solution ? https://github.com/lobobrowser/LoboBrowser

Comment: Maybe. I've never dealt with either.